# how to use new version to scrape foursquare?

Tags: python, scrape

I'm trying to use this code to scrape venues from foursquare

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=500):
    
    venues_list=[]
    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        print(name)
            
        # Create the API request URL
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/nearby&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
            CLIENT_ID, 
            CLIENT_SECRET, 
            VERSION, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            radius, 
            LIMIT)
            
        # Make the GET request
        results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']
        
        # Return only relevant information for each nearby venue
        venues_list.append([(
            name, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            v['venue']['name'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
            v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
    nearby_venues.columns = ['Neighborhood', 
                  'Neighborhood Latitude', 
                  'Neighborhood Longitude', 
                  'Venue', 
                  'Venue Latitude', 
                  'Venue Longitude', 
                  'Venue Category']
    
    return(nearby_venues)
```

but I'm getting this error

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 410,
        "errorType": "deprecated",
        "errorDetail": "Usage of the V2 Places API has been deprecated for new Projects. Please see our updated documentation for V3 for more details: https://docs.foursquare.com/reference",
        "requestId": "619928ff498a047e3a81f23a"
    },
    "response": {}
}
```

what should I edit in my code so it works

I couldn't figure it out from this link
https://developer.foursquare.com/reference/place-search

**Update** with the solution of @Corralien:

This the result of results.json()
I'm trying to get Venue Venue Latitude Venue Longitude Venue Category I have to write more so my code is not mostly code

```
  'timezone': 'Europe/Helsinki'},
  {'fsq_id': '4adcdb23f964a520c76021e3',
   'categories': [{'id': 10031,
     'name': 'Science Museum',
     'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/museum_science_',
      'suffix': '.png'}}],
   'chains': [],
   'distance': 148,
   'geocodes': {'main': {'latitude': 60.171349882576,
     'longitude': 24.93154852286545}},
   'location': {'address': 'Pohjoinen Rautatiekatu 13',
    'country': 'FI',
    'cross_street': 'Arkadiankatu / Nervanderinkatu',
    'locality': 'Helsinki',
    'neighborhood': ['Etu-Töölö'],
    'postcode': '00100',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `headers` with an `APIKEY` instead of `CLIENT_ID` / `CLIENT_SECRET` in the `get` url:

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=500):
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'APIKEY'
    }

    URL = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/search?ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'

    venues_list = []
    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        print(name)

        url = URL.format(lat, lng, radius, LIMIT)
        data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

        # do stuff here to process venues_list
        for record in data['results']:
            venues_list.append({
                'Neighborhood': name,
                'Neighborhood Latitude': lat,
                'Neighborhood Longitude': lng,
                'Venue': record['name'],
                'Venue Latitude': record['geocodes']['main']['latitude'],
                'Venue Longitude': record['geocodes']['main']['longitude'],
                'Venue Category': record['categories'][0]['name'],
            })

    # do stuff here to create your dataframe
    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame(venues_list)

    return(nearby_venues)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this very helpful,can you please help me write the whole function , this is my first big project I'm working on

Comment: I've no APIKEY to make requests. What is the output of `results.json()`?

Comment: for forsquare you need CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET, not API key , I tried your code this was the return <Response [503]>

Comment: I followed your link and you can test API call online. You can set an APIKEY and generate the code for the Python language.

Comment: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/places-api-getting-started#3-generate-an-api-key

Comment: ah sorry , i used the api key and this was the result <Response [200]>
can you please put your new code to work with the function I'm using

Comment: I can't I don't know the format of the `results.json()`!

Comment: sorry for the inconvinence please have a look at 2.5 section , this what I'm trying to get
https://github.com/bloonsinthesky/Data-Science-Portfolio/blob/main/The%20Battle%20of%20the%20Neighborhoods/The%20Battle%20of%20the%20Neighborhoods.ipynb

Comment: Try to run my code with `lat=60.172667; lng=24.932009; radius=500, LIMIT=5` and update your post with `results.json()` output.

Comment: Don't remove the content of your original post!!! Other people can't understand the problem now. Forget `results.json()`. Just check if you have some results with `results.text`. It should not raise an exception

Comment: updated it in the post , it worked wow thank you very much , can you please put it in the function , you really helped me a lot

Comment: sorry , i will edit it back to the original post at the end

Comment: @Kaokor. I updated my answer. I think it could help you. Is it clear enough?

Comment: thank you for your effort , i tried the code but I got this error (TypeError: string indices must be integers) , then  I tried to fill the function manually , it didn't work either

Comment: please help me i still couldn't figure it out , Im getting this error now "TypeError: string indices must be integers" ,on here "---> 19             v['venue']['name']," ,,, this is the result of "results.json()"  {'results': [{'fsq_id': '4adcdb23f964a520dc6021e3',
   'categories': [{'id': 10004,
     'name': 'Art Gallery',
     'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/artgallery_',
      'suffix': '.png'}}],
   'chains': [],
   'distance': 81,
   'geocodes': {'main': {'latitude': 60.172127213487165,
     'longitude': 24.93101........,

Comment: Save the result in a file with `import json; open('results.json', 'w').write(json.dumps(results.json(), indent=4))`. Share the file with wetransfer or dropbox.

Comment: I tried to put `["response"]['groups'][0]['items']`  after `results = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()` but start to get the error" key error response"

Comment: The format of the response has changed between the 2 versions of API, that's why it doesn't work now. Your last step is to extract values from this json response.

Comment: ahhh okay now i understant , this is the format of the response `{'results': [{'fsq_id': '4adcdb23f964a520dc6021e3',
   'categories': [{'id': 10004,
     'name': 'Art Gallery',
     'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/artgallery_',
      'suffix': '.png'}}],
   'chains': [],
   'distance': 81,
   'geocodes': {'main': {'latitude': 60.172127213487165,
     'longitude': 24.93101423081712}},
   'location': {'address': 'Nervanderinkatu 3',
    'country': 'FI',`

Comment: `'cross_street': '',
    'locality': 'Helsinki',
    'postcode': '00100',
    'region': 'Uusimaa'},
   'name': 'Taidehalli',
   'related_places': {'children': [{'fsq_id': '56824de0498ed3cdaa94c7ce',
      'name': 'Kioski Shop at Kunsthalle'},` can you tell me how to get the name and location lat and long and the venue category

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5x9rfobyc9l5jn/json.txt?dl=0
this is the whole json response 
I really appreciate your help but I don't know how to interept json file

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it should work. Can you try it please?